# Page cache behavior guarantees and log files

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, cache, buffer

Are there any guarantees as to when and in what order dirty pages are written out to disk? In the specific case of log structured files (files that are only ever appended to), is it possible for dirty pages to accumulate and be written to disk out of order?

For example, imagine a log file with the following dirty pages that have accumulated...

```
1: file_offset=16kb page_len=4kb <-- dirty
2: file_offset=20kb page_len=4kb <-- dirty
3: file_offset=24kb page_len=4kb <-- dirty
```

Will Linux write out the above dirty pages in order or is there a chance they they'll get written out of order? If out of order writing is a possibility, how do databases and applications that generate log files handle this? For example, if page 3 gets written out first and the OS crashes before it can write out 1 and 2, there'll be a 8kb filehole.

Comment: *how do databases and applications that generate log files handle this?*  In general, they **don't**. Log files like this are merely records of what happened - they're informational, not critical. If you need a guarantee like this, you're using the wrong tool for the job.  File systems are data stores, they aren't messaging mediums.

Comment: That doesn't sound even remotely correct, nor does it answer the question. My understanding is that write-ahead logs are used for database recover. Definitely critical. Definitely not "purely informational". Nothing to do with it being a "messaging medium".

Comment: *that write-ahead logs are used for database recover* Proper databases bypass the page cache and directly manipulate data, explicitly making sure it's safely  on disk.  The lack of specifics in your question and your "out of order" statement implies sequentially-written text log files - which a lot of people do *try* to misuse as a communications channel.  Sometimes it even works, if "works most of the time, kinda/maybe/eventually" is an acceptable definition of "works" for you.

Comment: Once again, what you're saying doesn't sound correct. The information I'm seeing online says that different databases have different syncing strategies. For example, Cassandra defaults to fsync its WAL every 10 seconds. Postgres and SQLite also fsync. LevelDB leaves it up to Linux. But, the question is about how Linux flushes out pages for append-only scenarios. Forget about the usecases.

Comment: And just what does `fsync()` do?  Forces data to storage, taking the page cache out of the equation.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sqlite uses the fsync() approach, but it does not fsync() every OS page individually.  That would limit performance. So it has to deal with some situations where some OS pages might have been written, but others might not. SQLite claims in docs to be pessimistic about what *order* those pages are written in, and uses a 32-bit checksum to reduce the chance that it causes a problem. Of course that doesn't work if you get unlucky with the checksum. (The same approach also reduces problems if the FS returns complete garbage for *all* the unsynced pages, after the crash).

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yet again, what you're saying doesn't sound correct at all. It doesn't take the page cache out of the question. The OS can still choose to flush pages to disk inbetween fsyncs. sourcejedi's comment about checksums makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Will Linux write out the above dirty pages in order or is there a chance they they'll get written out of order?

I'm not sure.

> If out of order writing is a possibility, how do databases and applications that generate log files handle this?

https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html#_dealing_with_garbage_written_into_journal_files

> SQLite assumes that the underlying filesystem can reorder write requests and that the page count can be burned into oxide first even though its write request occurred last. So as a second line of defense, SQLite also uses a 32-bit checksum on every page of data in the rollback journal. This checksum is evaluated for each page during rollback while rolling back a journal as described in section 4.4. If an incorrect checksum is seen, the rollback is abandoned. Note that the checksum does not guarantee that the page data is correct since there is a small but finite probability that the checksum might be right even if the data is corrupt. But the checksum does at least make such an error unlikely.